# Jquery maphighlight areas using id or class

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I am using jquery maphighlight and I have a problem highlighting individual areas on an image map,   i need to be able to always higlight aread with id2 and id4 for example, so that it will be always another color and when i click other areas the color stays on, right now onload its red but onclick  the color dissapears
.map is a class of the image i use,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.map').maphilight({
  fillColor: 'FF00000',
  fillOpacity: 0.5
});

var data = $('#id3').data('maphilight') || {};  
data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
$('#id34').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight'); 
});
```

but i want to to call a certain area with an id like this, which does not work

these are some of the areas i need to c

```
<img src="/images/test_map.png" class="map" usemap="#simple" />

<map class="tabs" name="simple">  
<area id="id1" href="#" shape="poly" coords="364,296,386,265,410,280,403,291,367,299" alt="Link" title=""/>
<area id="id2" href="#" shape="poly" coords="428,258,403,291,444,283,452,273" alt="Link" title=""/>
<area id="id3" href="#" shape="poly" coords="403,243,427,259,409,279,389,264" alt="Link" title=""/>
<area id="id4" href="#" shape="poly" coords="417,220,442,236,426,255,403,241" alt="Link" title=""/>
<area id="id5" href="#" shape="poly" coords="466,251,451,272,428,258,442,237" alt="Link" title=""/>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it, All i need is to highlight some areas on the map with a different color to show that the land is bought. or reserved
how does metadata work in maphighlight?

Comment: Some extra code please ... otherwise we can just imagine what you are toalking about

Comment: I think you use wrong data function http://api.jquery.com/data/